# Ionic splash screen and app size issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen

Since `ionic resource --splash` doesn't work for some reason as it should, I have manually exported those several dimensions for splash screen from `splash.psd`. I have copied those files to `resources/android/splash` and noticed that now my app doesn't have 7MB anymore, but 55...which I think is a huge change.

Is that normal?

Comment: No, it's not normal! It's due to the size of the images you added for splash screen, Check the size of the images you added! And why you didn't add them to `drawable` folder?

Comment: its not normal check your image size

Comment: rename your `.ipa` or `.apk` into `.zip`. Then unzip the file and check all folder sizes.

Comment: What does folder have to do with it? it is the same size in one folder or other. If I save it from psd to png, one image is about 5MB, if I do it to jpg it gets about 1MB...